# Query is not showing proper result

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

the Query join two tables on ProductID.The tables name are "product" and "SpecialOfferProduct". What i want is to join tables on ProductID where the Id is same select Name from Product. I did in this way but its not showing me the Name of the products.

```
 private void Button_Click_8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (LinqContainer context = new LinqContainer())
            {
                List<Product> pro=new List<Product>() ;


                var specialOffer = (from c in context.SpecialOfferProducts
                                           join p in pro on c.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                                            select new {p.Name})
                                            .ToList();
                grid.ItemsSource = specialOffer;

            }
```

Comment: are you sure that the list specialOffer is empty ? (just to check the error in the query or the dataGrid)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var specialOffer = (from c in context.SpecialOfferProducts
                                       join p in context.Products on c.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                                        select p.Name)
                                        .ToList();
```

Instead of

```
  var specialOffer = (from c in context.SpecialOfferProducts
                                       join p in pro on c.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                                        select new {p.Name})
                                        .ToList();
```

Comment: join p in context.Products on c.ProductID equals p.ProductID      thats solve my problem "Thanks anyways"